# Is there a collection of Objective-C wrappers to boost libraries?

Tags: c++, objective-c, boost

Using boost.org within a Cocoa project is not really complicated. I'm using opaque pointers as described here:  [Can I separate C++ main function and classes from Objective-C and/or C routines at compile and link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226912/can-i-separate-c-main-function-and-classes-from-objective-c-and-or-c-routines)

So I have written a few Objective-C wrappers around the boost libraries I'm using (Graph, Spirit,...) to have a consistent style in my programs (and to avoid contamining all my project so that it eventually becomes fully Objective-C++)

Before going on I would like to know if such wrappers already exist (as an opensource project) ?

Comment: What's the point? Why not just use Objective-C++?

Comment: Objective-C++ was specifically created to address the issue of interoping legacy C++ code with Apple's Cocoa. (Which is how they ported Photoshop, and other Adobe softwares to Apple). So Boost + Objective-C will require Objective-C++

Comment: Although if you're doing the wrappers manually each time, you can have the machine generate it for you.

Answer (score 1):

there are no ready-made wrappers AFAIK...
maybe that helps:

boostoniphone:
https://github.com/root42/boostoniphone-with-objc-nil-fix