# Calling Objective C++ methods from Objective C Classes

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

Is it possible to Call the Objective- C++ classes and methods from the Objective C Class?

Already we have written a project with Objective C code. Now we have one C++ class to be integrated, So i thought to change only one Class to Objective C++ which interacts with native C++ Classes others will remain in Objective C.
Is it possible? Could anyone can help me for better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. As long as the interface of the class is C-ish, Objective-C doesn't care if the implementation is Objective-C or Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. Just hide C++ fields in extension. There is example:

```
//.h-file
@interface IntVector: NSObject

- (int) valueAtIndex:(NSUInteger) idx;
- (NSUInteger) size;
- (void) insertValue:(int) val atIndex:(NSUInteger) idx;

@end

//.mm-file
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

@interface IntVector()
{
    vector<int> _vals;
}
@end

@implementation IntVector

- (int) valueAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    return _vals[idx];
}

- (NSUInteger) size
{
    return _vals.size();
}

- (void) insertValue:(int) val atIndex:(NSUInteger) idx
{
    _vals.indest(_vals.begin()+idx, val);
}

@end
```

You will be able use this class with any other objective-c code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you restrict your use of C++ types to the implementation file, you can call all of your ObjC++ classes from regular Objective C. There are a few gotchas, like wrapping any "loose" functions that you import in 'extern "C"' (like you would do when mixing C++ and straight C), but if you can assume a moderately recent version of Xcode (and don't need support for 32-bit MacOS), you can easily do all of that with a class extension (aka "class continuation").

If you want some tips and tricks about that topic, I was a guest on an episode of NSBrief a while ago where I talked at length about pretty much every aspect of using ObjC++: http://nsbrief.com/113-uli-kusterer/

You may also find an answer on this similar question: [Can I separate C++ main function and classes from Objective-C and/or C routines at compile and link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226912/can-i-separate-c-main-function-and-classes-from-objective-c-and-or-c-routines/2263291#2263291)