# Adding C++ Object to Objective-C Class

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to mix C++ and Objective-C, I've made it most of the way but would like to have a single interface class between the Objective-C and C++ code.  Therefore I would like to have a persistent C++ object in the ViewController interface.

This fails by forbidding the declaration of 'myCppFile' with no type:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GLView.h"
#import "myCppFile.h"

@interface GLViewController : UIViewController <GLViewDelegate>
{
    myCppFile cppobject;
}

@end
```

However this works just fine in the .mm implementation file (It doesn't work because I want cppobject to persist between calls)

```
#import "myCppFile.h"
@implementation GLViewController
- (void)drawView:(UIView *)theView
{
    myCppFile cppobject;
    cppobject.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use [opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) and only include C++ headers in the file that implements your Objective-C class. That way you don't force other files that include the header to use Objective-C++:

```
// header:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GLView.h"

struct Opaque;

@interface GLViewController : UIViewController <GLViewDelegate>
{
    struct Opaque* opaque;
}
// ...
@end
```

---

```
// source file:
#import "myCppFile.h"

struct Opaque {
    myCppFile cppobject;
};

@implementation GLViewController
// ... create opaque member on initialization

- (void)foo
{
    opaque->cppobject.doSomething();
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, the other suggestions didn't seem to work and I ended up declaring my object as an "id*" then casting it to the correct type everywhere I wanted to use it.  This seems like the same idea, but is much cleaner since I don't have to do all the extra casts.

Comment: I'd always prefer opaque pointers over casts - it might be a bit more work, but you get full type safety back.

Comment: I've been playing with opaque pointers for this, which I use extensively for C/C++ wrapping, but so far I haven't seen the real benefit. Can you compare this style (along with some code showing how "opaque" is allocated and released) to the void* based style here: http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-objc-20

Comment: *Note:* Rob Napier posted a nice [update](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486) on wrapping C++.

Comment: thanks a million for this code example. I was 2 steps shy of throwing my mac out the window.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche dont we have to initialize the c++ class to create an object in opaque pointer ?? i was using the above example but got exc_bad_access in first class method access ..

Comment: @shishir123 Sure, that is why there is the placeholder comment for _"... create opaque member on initialization"_.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that all files that include `GLViewController.h` are Objective-C++ sources (*.mm).

When you include C++ code in the header of your view controller, all sources that import this header must be able to understand it, so they must be in Objective-C++

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the C++ objects in an interface block in your .mm file.

In .mm:

```
#include "SomeCPPclass.h"

@interface SomeDetailViewController () {
    SomeCPPclass*    _ipcamera;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)blabla;
@end
```

Comment: Take close note of the () - that's the black(et) magic that makes this work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the following flag to `true` in your project settings:

```
GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS = YES
```

This should allow you to instantiate C++ objects in your Objective-C classes.

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  I'm using Xcode 3.2.1 and the 3.0 iphone SDK.