# use c++ template class from objective c file

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c

I would like to use a C++ class in an objective c application.
How to achieve this?

Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: For your possible next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class/2262395

Comment: you answer before I ask ;) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using "Objective-C++". You should read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html), but the short version is that you may mix C++ and Objective-C in files with the extension ".mm". It's not magic (C++ classes and Objective-C classes are still separate things), but you can now use them in the same code.