# Calling C++ function from objective C class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c++

I want to call a c++ function from my objective C class i am not sure how to call it.Please somebody help me by giving some sample codes or useful links
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use Objective-C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710507/mixing-objective-c-and-c

Answer (score 6):

Change the `.m` extension to `.mm` on the Objective-C file to make it [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to switching your class implementation file to Objective-C++ is to declare the C++ function as `extern "C"`, assuming its arguments are all C types. Place that declaration inside a C-compatible C++ header file and include it from both the C++ file that implements the function and from the Objective-C file that calls it. This will of course only work if the data types of parameters and the return type are pure C types, but is in some cases "cleaner" than the Objective-C++ approach.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what pmjordan said, if you have a .m file calling in to a .mm or .cpp, make sure that the main header of the .mm or .cpp, where the functions you are calling are declared, have  conditionally compiled `extern "C"` like this .h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void functionA(void);
void functionB(const char *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When this header is included as part of the .mm or .cpp, the `extern "C"` will do the right thing, and when the .h is compiled as part of the calling .c or .m file that calls those functions, the `extern "c"` is excluded and will not cause the compiler to complain.

Using this solution will prevent you from needlessly changing .m files into .mm files just so you can simply call C routines in c++ files.