# Calling NSLog from C++: "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

Tags: c++, objective-c, nslog

When I call NSLog from C++, Xcode complains that the format string passed to NSLog is not a literal string.  Here's a line of code that triggers the warning:

```
NSLog(CFSTR("Leaking?"));
```

I'm not aware of any way to code a literal NSString in C++, and I don't see a relevant warning I can turn off in the project settings.  Is there a way to call NSLog from C++ without triggering this message?  I'm using Xcode 4.2.1.

Edit:  This really is C++ code.  I usually avoid Objective-C++, sticking to either Objective-C or plain old C++, because there's no official documentation about what works in Objective-C++ and what doesn't.  I've only found vague warnings that (for example) there may be issues with some parts of the STL.  I use templates, the STL, and other "advanced" features of C++, so I want to play it safe.

Edit #2, the solution:  I just figured out clang supports a lot more warning flags than are actually documented.  (It should have been obvious from the long list of warnings that Xcode offered me.)  I tried -Wno-format-nonliteral a la gcc, and now Xcode is happy.

Comment: If you are calling `NSLog`, which is part of Foundation, then you are using Objective-C. Use `@"Leaking?"` and make sure your file has a `.mm` extension.

Comment: @Joe ... unless he means Objective-C++ ?

Comment: @csl I moved the comment to an answer with some clarification.

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do is write `@"this"` to create a literal NSString object.

So replace that line with `NSLog(@"Leaking?");` and you should be fine.

You might have to rename your file with the extension `.mm` to make sure it is compiled as Objective-C++ (the mutant love-child of Objective-C and C++). If you don't want to do that, you could make a wrapper function in a tiny mm file that calls NSLog, and then call that function from your C++ code. It would look like this:

```
void MyNSLog(const char *message)
{
    NSLog(@"%s", message);
}
```

Note that the reason the compiler is giving you grief is that using anything but an immutable string literal (where the contents are known at compile time) is a security risk. Otherwise, the format string could be changed to include format specifiers (e.g., `%d`) for parameters that aren't there. If that happened, NSLog would just get random pointers from the stack and something bad could happen. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677824/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments) for more info.)

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to define a helper function in a separate .mm file.  I didn't use it this time, but I'm sure it's going to come in handy in the future, since I'm generally cautious about using Objective-C++.

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling `NSLog`, which is part of [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog), then you are using Objective-C. Use `NSLog(@"Leaking?");` and make sure your file has a `.mm` extension to make it clear that you are mixing `Objective-C` and `C++`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm confused. Why not just name this a `.m` extension instead of `.mm`, if Foundation is Objective-C?  Did you mean to say that NSLog is Objective C++ instead, or am I confused? Thanks!

Comment: I was speculating that maybe `NSLog` was getting called from a `.cpp` file which would not work because `NSLog` is only `Objective-C`. And to mix `Objective-C` and `C++` the extension [should be `.mm`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727249/calling-c-function-from-objective-c-class/7727308#7727308).