# How is my string potentially unsecure?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling NSLog from C++: “Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793199/calling-nslog-from-c-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-potentially-inse)
>   [Why is my string potentially unsecure in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961363/why-is-my-string-potentially-unsecure-in-my-ios-application)

I have this code to log the number of elements in my NSMutableDictionary called "myDictionary" in objective-c.

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myDictionary count]]);
```

XCode warns me that "Format string is not a string literal. Potentially insecure."

Why? Aren't I using a secure formatted string as opposed to directly casting the count?

Comment: Duplicates: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793199/calling-nslog-from-c-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal-potentially-inse), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961363/why-is-my-string-potentially-unsecure-in-my-ios-application).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you pass to `NSLog` is interpreted like a format string, so the appropriate way to do this is `NSLog(@"%d", myDictionary.count);`.

The reason it's "unsafe" is that it's possible to crash the program in cases like this:

```
NSString *someString = @"The integer format specifier is %d";
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]);
```

The input to `NSLog` is treated like a format string, but there's no corresponding value for the `%d` at the end. In your case it's not a problem, but the compiler isn't smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 6):

NSLog() already assumes that you'll be passing in a formatted string. Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [myDictionary count]);
```