# C source file doesn't get build into .o in XCode

Tags: c, xcode, gcc

Now this warning that i'm getting has been around but still i can't seem to fix this..

> [WARN] no rule to process file 'dns.c' of type sourcecode.c for architecture i386

I've touched some property like that in the XCode IDE somewhere but how do i get this fixed again.. 
With all the other sources there's no probs with generating .o code..

Thanx..

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710520/1758762

Comment: @duDE I don't think so.

Comment: @dmirkitanov Nope - this isn't a `.h` file. The error makes sense for a header file as there shouldn't be a rule to build those, but not for `.c`.

Comment: In the settings for your target, can you go to the "Build Rules" tab, select "All", find "System C Rule" and click "Copy to target"?

Comment: duDE I've seen those but that's not it.. Like James is saying it has to do with some rule of how a source should be build & it comes after checking dependencies.. I'm not winning here..
Sorry for being a rookie in XCode, I used to do DevStudio..

Comment: I think i've solved this by completely removing the file from the project and adding a new one.. Now it is compiling with a few link errors but at least i'm on track again.. Appreciate the speedy responses..