# Display an input box in Mac OSX using c++

Tags: c++, macos

I wanted to create a simple input dialog box using C++ on MacOSX. I do not want to any use any cross platform library(QT and wxwidget) for my project. I have find many solution available on objective C to create the dialog box but not for C++.

Ref: [How to display an input box in Mac OSX using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392802/how-to-display-an-input-box-in-mac-osx-using-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20393897/1312143) to the question you linked that mentions [`CFUserNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfusernotification). That's a C API that can be called from C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an input box in Mac OSX using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392802/how-to-display-an-input-box-in-mac-osx-using-c)