# 'algorithm' file not found

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to do a simple console app in Xcode using the following library:

https://github.com/marstone/ingress-ios/tree/master/s2-geometry

I'm finding the library but its not finding the algorithm library.

Sample example code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "S2Geometry.h"

#include "s2.h"
#include "s2cellid.h"
#include "s2latlng.h"
#include "s2latlngrect.h"
#include "s2regioncoverer.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        S2LatLngRect rect = S2LatLngRect(S2LatLng::FromDegrees(MIN(37.78272, 37.781719), MIN(-121.971427, -121.972007)), S2LatLng::FromDegrees(MAX(37.78272,
37.781719), MAX(-121.971427, -121.972007)));
    }
    return 0; }
```

I get the following error:

```
 ./s2-geometry/s2.h:6:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `s2-geometry` library is written in Objective-C++, but your example code is using the Objective-C compiler. The error about the missing file occurred because `algorithm` is a C++ header that is unavailable to Objective-C.

If you change your example file's extension from `.m`, to `.mm`, your code will use the Objective-C++ compiler and the error should disappear.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710507/mixing-objective-c-and-c) for more information on mixing Objective-C and Objective-C++.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem in my Xcode project.(Xcode version 10.2). I refer to the link.[Xcode 10 beta 4 - stdlibc++ headers not found](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106114) and solve this problem by change Settings.

> Build Settings->Apple Clang - Language-C++ ->C++ Standard Library(libc++)

Answer (score 0):

Just running pod install worked for me

Answer (score -1):

According to Gemfield:
"build settings" --> "compile source as" --> object c++