# XCode Build Error - missing required module 'Algorithms'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build-error

**Background**

1. I was trying to upgrade old project from xcode 11.3 into xcode 12.4. The code is still on Swift 4.2
2. When try to build (any iOS device - arm64) every swift file in the project got same error:

```
 <unknown\>:0: error: missing required module '**Algorithms**'
```

[image]
3. After try to rebuild using xcode 11.3, then i found out that **arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface** is actually adding **import 'Algorithms'** in top of the file [image]

> //swift-interface-format-version: 1.0 
> // swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.8.41 clang-1200.0.32.8) 
> // swift-module-flags: -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -enable-librar -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivi checked -Onone -module-name Charts 
> import Algorithms 
> @_exported import Charts 
> import CoreGraphics

**Question**

- How to add this algorithms.h into the project/compilation process, so the project able to compile?
- What caused the compiler to add this? is it because the build setting > Swift Language Version > Swift 4.2 ?

**What i have tried**

- reinstall XCode Command Line Tools 12.4
- Build Settings->Apple Clang - Language-C++ ->C++ Standard Library(libc++) refference:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649385/algorithm-file-not-found]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem now solved.

It is appear that one of the library we are using, have dependency on new 'Algorithms' Swift ( https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms ) . Therefore we can resolve by doing 2 way

- adding the Algorithms Swift dependency to the projects
- revert the library into before using Algorithms Swift

Thanks.