# Table Arraylist sorted datastructure in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, sorting, data-structures

I have a datastructure in C++ `Table Arraylist sorted`, is there any equivalent in objective-c. It can be Third-party library. Thank you so much

Comment: `NS(Mutable)Array`? Else, you can use C++ with Objective-C (if you already have your code).

Comment: @Larme I have a code, is there any tutorial how to import c++ classess?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710507/mixing-objective-c-and-c