# C++ from SpeakHere in iPhone app

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, header, integration

I've made a template app where I've grabbed the recording part of the SpeakHere example and removed the file handling part, but I'm struggeling to get the C++ part of the app working right. As soon as it enters the C++ class, it gets syntax errors. If I don't import the header files from C++ (and then of course don't use the code) into my Objective C classes, all works fine. I cannot see the difference between how I'm doing it and the example is doing it. Can you see the difference?

I've posted the entire code here: http://github.com/niklassaers/testFFT

The build errors I get are:

```
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:91:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:91: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CAStreamBasicDescription'
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:298:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:298: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:299:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:299: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '==' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:301:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:301: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '!=' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:302:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:302: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<=' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:303:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:303: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '>=' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:304:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:304: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '>' token
testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:307:0 testFFT/CAStreamBasicDescription.h:307: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
testFFT/CAXException.h:65:0 testFFT/CAXException.h:65: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CAX4CCString'
testFFT/CAXException.h:87:0 testFFT/CAXException.h:87: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CAXException'
testFFT/AQRecorder.h:59:0 testFFT/AQRecorder.h:59: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'AQRecorder'
testFFT/RecorderLink.h:57:0 testFFT/RecorderLink.h:57: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'AQRecorder'
testFFT/RecorderLink.h:62:0 testFFT/RecorderLink.h:62: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'AQRecorder'
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indirectly including the C++ headers into plain Objective-C code (`.m`) - that won't work, you have to use [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) (`.mm`) all the way or encapsulate the C++ classes in Objective-C classes using [opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

One problematic chain:

- `Classes/MainViewController.m`, plain Objective-C, includes
- `RecorderLink.h`, includes
- `AQRecorder.h`, which is C++

Comment: So would it be your recommendation to rename MainViewController.m to MainViewController.mm ?

Comment: @niklassaers: Going with the chain above, i'd personally try to keep the already good seperation of C++ and Objective-C (application core and GUI layer) - in this example you only have to get the C++ include and the C++ pointer type out of `RecorderLink.h`. See here for one possible approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class/2262395#2262395

Comment: Voila, an implementation using opaque pointers has been pushed to github

Comment: PS, I still don't get how the SpeakHere example got around this problem, though

Comment: @niklassaers: Is that original one viewable online?

Comment: Yes, it's here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @niklassaers: From a quick glance through it, the plain Objective-C sources (`.m`) in that project simply don't include any C++ headers. E.g. in `SpeakHereViewController.h` they only forward declare `@class SpeakHereController`, instead of including its header which contains C++ includes.