# C++ stack in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, stack, objective-c++

I'd like to use a C++ stack type in Objective-C, but I'm running into some issues.  Here's a sample of what I would like to do:

```
#import <stack>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface A : NSObject {
    stack<SEL> selectorStack;
}

@end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile.  After messing around with the code for a while and trying different things, I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.  Can somebody tell me the best way to use a C++ stack within an Objective-C object or if it's even possible?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Well, KennyTM's answer worked on my example file, but for some reason when I tried to rename the class it quit working.  Here's the code I have right now:

```
#import <stack>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuLayer : NSObject {
    std::stack<SEL> selectorStack;
}

@end
```

The compiler spits out the following errors:

```
stack: No such file or directory
expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'std'
```

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally renamed it ending `.m` instead of `.mm`. Otherwise the C++ headers aren't in the header search paths (and you can't use C++ of course).

Comment: I double checked it, and the extension is .mm.  Just to be clear though, the interface is located in a header file.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: If the header is included in some plain Objective-C (`.m`) file you end up with the same problem. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class/2262395) for alternatives.

Comment: The opaque pointers worked perfectly.  Thanks gf.  If you were to copy your answer into a reply then I'll give you the check mark.  Thanks again.

Comment: Added it for future reference, but give the check-mark to KennyTM - he solved the problem as originally posted. I only fixed the follow-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@interface A : NSObject {
    std::stack<SEL> selectorStack;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.  I feel kind of stupid for not specifying the fully qualified class name.  When I changed this on my sample file, it fixed the problem.  However, I tried changing the name of the class to something else and the compiler spit out a couple of new errors.  I updated my post with more information.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For the second problem make sure you haven't accidentally renamed the file ending `.m` instead of `.mm`. Otherwise the C++ headers aren't in the header search paths (and you can't use C++ of course).

Also, if the header is included in some plain Objective-C file (`.m`) you end up with the same problem. You could avoid this e.g. by using [opaque pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class/2262395).