# How to incorporate C++ code in Objective-C project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

I'd like to use some C++ code in an Xcode project but I don't understand either language well enough yet to know how to proceed.  I've been at the Obj-C for a while and have an app on the app store, but still learning...

The code I want to use has two files with the same name and `.h` and `.c` extensions.  I would think they correspond to `.h` and `.m` files in Obj-C, but they lack the `@interface` and `@implementation` structure I'm familiar with.  And there's a `main.c` that I don't know what to do with.  It looks like it's the main program - should I try to pull its code out into my primary `viewController`?

Maybe a link to a good tutorial?  Maybe this question's too vague...

FYI - the code I want to use is for calculating sunrise and sunset times, and is located at: http://www.risacher.org/sunwait/

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions - I will probably have to do some more learning before I get this.  But I made some progress...

In `main.c` (seems weird to have a file called that...) there is a function(?) like this:

```
int mainFunction(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// a bunch of function-y stuff
}
```

It was called `main` but I changed it to `mainFunction` to get rid of an error.  Now it compiles and I can call it but the compiler warns me thus: `warning: implicit declaration of function 'mainFunction'` and it crashes after I call it.

Comment: That code is C, not C++.  It's a program, not a library, so you'd have to do some surgery on it to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your files have a `.c` extension, they are almost certainly C and not C++.  All you have to do is add them to the project and target and include the relevant `.h` file in the Objective-C where you call the C functions.

Now the fact that you used to have a function called `main()` tells us that you had a stand alone program.  Every stand alone program has to have a function called `main()`, it's the entry point for the program.  Your Objective-C application will have a function `main()` already which is why you were getting an error.  You can take the approach of renaming the duplicate and calling it but there are a number of pitfalls with that approach.

- As you found out, you need a function prototype to stop the implicit declaration warning.  This should be

  ```
  int mainFunction(int argc, char* argv[]);
  ```

  and should be in a header that you include in the .m file where you want to call it.
- In C, certain assumptions are made about the parameters.  `argc` is the number of `char*`s in argv.  `argv[0]` is conventionally the name of the program as invoked on the command line.  So `argc` must be at least 1 and `argv[0]` must point to a string.  The remaining `char*`s in argv point to the command line parameters.
- Typically, a command line program expects to be able to accept input from the keyboard and display output on the screen.  This is done through three file descriptors: stdin, stdout and stderr.  Stdin is for input, stdout is for normal output and stderr is for output of error and other 'out of band' messages.  Intercepting these file descriptors in a GUI application is non trivial.

I suggest you work through the basics of C to gain an understanding of it.  You can probably learn enough to progress your project in a day or two.  The classic text is [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29).  It's still one of the best IMHO.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to take a shortcut to using this algorithm, but it looks like I either need to learn some C, or work through the algorithm myself and really understand it to implement it directly in Obj-C.  Actually it might be fun to dig into it...

Comment: @Steve: You'll probably find that the `main()` function merely parses the command line parameters and then calls some other function or functions to do the real work.  And if they are well designed you will be able to call them directly and avoid the pitfalls I mentioned.  However, that will be easier to do if you have learned some C.  You shouldn't find that hard if you have already done some Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

> Now it compiles and I can call it but the compiler warns me thus: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mainFunction' and it crashes after I call it.

This is because, where you use this function, you do not forward-declare or include the declaration  of the function. In your Objective-C code, you should add the following bit of code:

```
int mainFunction(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Also note that the ".c" file extension is C code, not C++. Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you could just as easily change the extension to ".m", and you'd still get the same error since you need this forward declaration. I would strongly recommend familiarizing yourself with both C and C++ code before venturing into the world of Objective-C. If you wish to forgoe learning C++, then at the very least, you should strengthen your C knowledge before going into Objective-C, as the C fundamentals apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chapter in the Objective-C 2.0 guide here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1

Basically you can mix C++ and objective-C, but there are a couple of pitfalls.  It sounds like you may need to learn more about C++ in general before you explore the nuances of objective-C++

Answer (score 1):

Rename sources from .m to .mm, then they become Objective C++. You can instantiate and call C++ classes from Objective C code and vice versa. You cannot, though, derive ObjC classes from C++ classes and vice versa. Also, mind the calling conventions - the global functions in .m files are `extern "C"` as far as .mm/.cpp files are concerned.

Linking together .mm and .cpp works fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many tutorials about this unfortunately. I think this has been asked a couple of times in stackoverflow, so searching here will give you some hints. The first pitfall you would want to avoid is, you need to use the ".mm" extension for your obj-c files to enable the c++ extension.

- http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CPlusPlusInCocoa
- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html
- [Adding C++ Object to Objective-C Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class/2262395#2262395)
- http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-objc-20

One last pointer is, look at opensource projects e.g. chrome to see how they mix up obj-c and C++. Google search is also your friend :).