# passing C++ objects in Objective C++

Tags: cocoa, opencv, xcode4, objective-c++

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class) involving using opaque types, but I don't quite understand the sample code.

I've got some code which works...where I have several C++ data objects stored as instance variables in my controller.  I'd like to conform to MVC, and get all of this pushed down into a model object, and not my controller.

So what I have now that works looks like:

```
@interface WinController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate>
{
    cv::Mat object;
}
- (void)setObject:(const cv::Mat&)newObject;
@end

@implementation

- (void)setObject:(const cv::Mat&)newObject
{
    object = newObject;
}
@end
```

And this `setObject:` method is called by a different class's method:

```
- (void)constructObject
{
    cv::Mat object = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_64F);
    [myController setObject:object];
}
```

So I move the C++ object out of the controller and into a model class. The `@interface` and `@implementation` is exactly the same.  Just copied and pasted into a different class.

The `constructObject:` method changes to this:

```
- (void)constructObject
{
    cv::Mat object = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_64F);
    [myController.myModel setObject:object];
}
```

Now when I compile, I get a new warning:
`Instance method '-setObject:' not found. (return type defaults to 'id')`

So clearly I'm missing some subtlety on why method #1 works, and #2 doesn't.

Comment: The "subtlety" is almost certainly a typo or silly mistake in code you haven't posted.

Comment: Have you imported the .h file of the new model code from the file with the constructObject method?

Comment: I had.  And when I got the warning, I assumed there was an actual problem that the code would choke on at run time.  I tried running it, and it worked just fine.  I did eventually eliminate the error, by rearranging the order I imported the header files. Yuck.