# Using a C++ class as a protocol in a objective-c class

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, inheritance

I have an abstract class in pure c++ (with a pure virtual function), and i have to implement that in a objective c class, how would i do that?

if i declare,

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyOtherClass>
```

it throws an error telling protocol is not defined in MyOtherClass

Definition of C++ class:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    virtual void myFunc() = 0;
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this question can help accomplish the same behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262011/adding-c-object-to-objective-c-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol is a feature of Objective-C, Not C++.

Your MyClass can't use any non objective-c class as its protocol.

As said by *JeremyP*

> Make sure that any files that include that header are compiled as
>   Objective-C++ either by changing the extension to .mm or by changing
>   the file type to `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp`.

Comment: thank you, so how would i make my class implement the functions from the other class? normal inheritance? i guess we dont have multiple inheritance also in objective c

Comment: @HariKrishna: You can't. Objective-C methods are completely different, syntactically and semantically, from C++ methods. They are not interchangeable.