# Objective C objects as instance variables in C++ classes

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, class, objective-c++

I'm attempting to modify a C++ class in such a way that an Objective C object is one of its instance variables.

In essence, this question is like the reverse of this: [C++ classes as instance variables of an Objective-C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056911/c-classes-as-instance-variables-of-an-objective-c-class)

The header file `MyCPPClass.h` looks like this:

```
namespace my_namespace{

    class MyCPPClass: public my_namespace::OperationHandler {
     public:
         void someFunc();

     private:
         void otherFunc();
    };
}
```

And the `MyCPPClass.mm` file looks like this:

```
#include "MyCPPClass.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void my_namespace:: MyCPPClass:: someFunc() {
    NSLog(@"I can run ObjC here! Yahoo!");

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"download_url_goes_here"]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
   // handle the data
   }];

}

void my_namespace:: MyCPPClass:: otherFunc() {
    NSLog(@"I can run ObjC here! Yahoo!");
}
```

The issue here is that I need to store a reference to an object created in `someFunc()` and then use it in `otherFunc()`. This object is an instance of `NSURLSessionTask`. My background in C++ is very limited :(. What is the least intrusive way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can store it as a void*, according to this [Pass an Objective-C object to a function as a void * pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916491/pass-an-objective-c-object-to-a-function-as-a-void-pointer)

So your header would become:

```
namespace my_namespace{

    class MyCPPClass: public my_namespace::OperationHandler {
        public:
            void someFunc();

        private:
            void otherFunc();
            void *mySessionTask;
    };
}
```

If you want to send a message to it you first cast it back to what it is supposed to be:

```
[(NSURLSessionTask*)mySessionTask someMessageWithArg: foo]
```

Comment: But then you lose the memory management of the variable which is based on the type.